# How to fake Azure Table Storage in .NET for Unit Testing?

Tags: unit-testing, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I am working on a system that uses Azure Table Storage. In other systems (e.g., SQL, File based, etc), I can write a fake that allows me to test my data persistence logic. However, I can't see an easy way to create a fake for the Azure Table Service.

I could create a new IIS project that behaves the same way, but that isn't a good way to write a unit test, it is more of an integration test.

Any thoughts on how to unit test data access code that uses the Azure Table Storage client?

Answer (score 1):

I was considering this more for integration testing, but I suppose it could also work for unit testing.  Meet [Azure Storage Emulator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-use-emulator/).  It sounds like a very awesome tool for testing Azure Blob, Queue and Table Services.  I'm play around with it and try to post my findings if I can remember to do so.

Answer (score 0):

This is something I'm currently considering myself, but I haven't tried it yet.

TableServiceContext inherets from  DataServiceContext, so I figure if you could inject the TableServiceContext as a DataServiceContext, you could model the Table Store using data services.

Taking it a step further, if you use Entity Framework "Code First" to create your Entity Model - you could just use the Table Entities you've already created as the backing entities for your data service and everything should work smoothly.

That's the theory at least. I've never tried it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storageclient.tableservicecontext_members.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm sure that I completely follow - are you suggesting using WCF Data Services (locally) as the target for the Azure table tests? If so, I like the idea, but I am concerned about the odd differences between the two. Let me know if you have tried it out, and I'll do the same. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I use an in-memory implementation of ICloudTableStorage, which you can pass into eg ReliableCloudTableRepository.

You can find the code here: https://gist.github.com/4078750

Comment: This links to a file with no code in it.  I don't know what it used to contain, but at this point it is nothing.

Comment: @DanCsharpster  Ah yes. When the question was originally posted, I think everybody was using CloudFx's Azure SDK.  I eventually deprecated my gist in favour of a class that became available in their own libraries, which is what the gist now states: `// use Microsoft.Experience.CloudFx.Framework.Storage.InMemoryCloudTableStorage`.  You can see the old code under revisions  (https://gist.github.com/timiles/4078750/revisions), but since it is dependent on CloudFx, there's no reason not to use their own class now.  I could look into reinstating it, but note that Azure has changed a lot since 2012.

Comment: Thanks @Tim Iles!  I'll check that out.  FYI, I'm also checking into Azure Storage Emulator.  It looks like it has some potential for integration tests.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-use-emulator/

Answer (score 0):

I know there are several solutions posted here, but here's the one I came up with:

http://azurator.blogspot.com/2013/07/unit-testing-azure-table-storage-queries.html

This is only a solution for when you're querying objects using `CloudTableQuery<T>`, but it helped me a lot. If you're trying to get a more full implementation you could also create a shim for `DataServiceContext.SaveChanges()` that might get you the updating portion.